# Telegram Telethon multiple keyword search

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telethon

I am using Telethon package in Python to search for unique message from a channel. I am using the following code to search from the channel I am subscribed to:

> ```
> for index, x in enumerate(client.iter_messages(group_name, search='New York')):
>     TODO
> ```

As you can notice, I am searching for a single keyword "New York". I would like to search for multiple keywords using Logical Operator like "New York or Miami or Dallas or Houston"

Any idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

When you use the parameter search= you are using the `messages.search` request from the API which does the search server side so you can't use logical operations.

To use logical operations you could use iter_messages and get all messages then get their .text and search in those.